# can we distinguish string/int value in yaml file using yaml BaseLoader?

Tags: python, python-3.x, yaml

I have a yaml file with the following data:

```
apple: 1
banana: '2'
cat: "3"
```

My project is parsing it using Python(yaml.BaseLoader) and want to deduce that `"apple"` is associated with an integer, using the isinstance()?

But in my case, the value `isinstance(config['apple'], int)` is showing `FALSE` and `isinstance(config['apple'], str)` is `TRUE`.

I think it makes sense as well, as we are using BaseLoader, so is there a way to update this to include integer without replacing the BaseLoader as the project's parsing script is getting used at many places?

Comment: What's the reason for using BaseLoader instead of a loader that would do this conversion for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've noticed, the base loader doesn't distinguish between scalar types (the behavior is via `BaseConstructor.construct_scalar`).

I'm not quite sure if this is what you want, but...

There's no safe way (that wouldn't affect other libraries using `BaseLoader`) to add integers to `BaseLoader`, but if you're willing to do a single search-and-replace to replace the use of `BaseLoader` with something else, you can do

```
class OurLoader(BaseLoader):
    pass


OurLoader.add_constructor(
    "tag:yaml.org,2002:int", SafeConstructor.construct_yaml_int,
)

# Borrowed from the yaml module itself:

YAML_INT_RE = re.compile(
    r"""
    ^(?:[-+]?0b[0-1_]+
    |[-+]?0[0-7_]+
    |[-+]?(?:0|[1-9][0-9_]*)
    |[-+]?0x[0-9a-fA-F_]+
    |[-+]?[1-9][0-9_]*(?::[0-5]?[0-9])+)$""",
    re.X,
)
OurLoader.add_implicit_resolver(
    "tag:yaml.org,2002:int", YAML_INT_RE, list("-+0123456789")
)
```

to end up with a loader that knows integers but nothing else.

Comment: Thanks! Can we override the construct_scalar() to support string and integer both? @AKX

Comment: You can take a look at `yaml/resolver.py` and `yaml/loader.py` to see how to add those resolver-constructor pairs.